# TypeError: GoogleAuth.LocalWebserverAuth() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-api-python-client, pydrive

I am trying to authenticate google api and after following all the necessary steps like making credentials and installing pydrive, I am faced with this error when running the main.py module `TypeError: GoogleAuth.LocalWebserverAuth() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`
Do you guys have any idea how to fix it. thank you in advance :)

main.py code

```
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python "`TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"` occurs if you call a method on the class instead of on an instance of the class.

You are missing `from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth`

## pydrive

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped you it will also improve your reputation.